# ArcPy x64 - Create Enterprise Geodatabase in SQL Server Fails

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, windows-7, 64bit

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop Standard 10.1 SP1 on Windows 7 SP1 x64. SQL Server Native Client 11.0 is installed for both 32 bit and 64 bit. I've also got SQL Server 2012 x64 installed (client tools and database engine).

Running an ArcPy based script in Python 2.7 x64 crashes Python.exe when it tries to create an Enterprise Geodatabase in SQL Server 2012 with this line:

```
arcpy.CreateEnterpriseGeodatabase_management("SQLSERVER", sDbServerName, sDbName, "OPERATING_SYSTEM_AUTH", "", "", "DBO_SCHEMA", "", "", "", sLicenseKey)
```

The error is:

> Unable to load server library (c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\bin\sdesqlsrvr101.dll), Error = -324

Using SDE_SCHEMA and/or database authentication don't work either.

The workaround is to use 32 bit Python. However, our standard development environment is x64 (for performance reasons).

Any ideas how to get this working in x64 Python?

Comment: Not sure about SQLServer, but with Oracle you need to have the 64 bit dlls found before the 32 bit dlls.  Ie, your 64 bit bin directory has to be before your 32 bit bin directory in the PATH.